# Neo4J Java API getRelationships not returning all relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Edit: see comment and ignore this question

I have a Neo4J plugin with this code:

```
enum VrtrackRelationshipTypes implements RelationshipType { created_for }
Direction in = Direction.INCOMING;

System.out.println("will get nodes created_for study with node id " + study.getId());
int count = 0;
for (Relationship slRel: study.getRelationships(VrtrackRelationshipTypes.created_for, in)) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Which returns:

> will get nodes created_for study with node id 1453769
>
> 3445

However, using the web frontend and some cypher:

```
match (n)-[:created_for]->(m) where id(m) = 1453769 return count(distinct(n))
```

Returns:

> 3631

How can this be?

Comment: Turns out this is my own mistake. The java snippet above is a simplified version of the actual code, and in reality the loop is interrupted by an error, making the count too short

Answer (score 0):

In on place you counted **all** relationships, in the other you counted **distinct** end-nodes.

try to run this and see what it returns:

```
match (n)-[r:created_for]->(m) 
where id(m) = 1453769 
return count(*) as paths, count(r) as rels, 
       count(n) as seen_n, count(distinct n) as distinct_n
```